# How can I bind querystring parameters using Knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: roomba">
  <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
  <a href="/arena/bots/status?id=1234">View Status</a>
</div>
```

My dilemma is that I'd like the id parameter in the anchor tag to be bound to the id of the roomba currently being iterated over.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try Defining the URL in the view binding. Then bind to that url in data-bind="attr"

Take a look at this example:

```
<ul id="MemberSearch" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: members">    
<li> <a  data-bind="attr: { href:Url},text:Name"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Then in your model

```
function Member(data) {
            this.Name = ko.observable(data.FirstName + ' ' + data.LastName);
            this.Url = ko.observable("/member/details/"+data.Id);
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do it as

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '?id=' + $data.id}"></a>
```

Worked for my example anyway

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the [attr](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding?

Comment: Something along the lines of: <a data-bind="attr: { href: '/arena/bots/status?id='+id }">View Status</a> ?

Comment: Doesn't work. I have this: <a href="#" data-bind="text: Title, attr: {href: '/dosomething/'+ Id}"></a>
What I get back in href is this: http://localhost/dosomething/function... and then a long compressed js function.

Comment: attr works with knockout but does not work with the latest knockout mapping plugin. I guess you are using that because I am and I have the same problem with the function being output instead of the id.

Comment: try calling Id as a function like this: <a href="#" data-bind="text: Title, attr: {href: '/dosomething/'+ Id()}"></a>

Comment: @rushonerok it works!  <a class="btn btn-small" href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: '/#/todoDetail/'+Id()}">